# how to securely add password or secrets into a helm values.yaml file that will be commited in git?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, apache-superset

I'm using superset helm chart and we are committing into git our `values.yaml` file. The issue is that some fields of `values.yaml` want me to include a password or secrets example:

```
supersetNode:
  connections:

    db_host: "10.100.0.0"
    db_port: "5432"
    db_user: myuser
    db_pass: MY_SECRET_PASS
```

How can I avoid injecting the secret here since this `values.yaml` file will be git committed?

This is the template file where the secret will end up being used:

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:helmfile]; does Helmfile's docs on [Secrets](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote-secrets/) help?  Is your question about programming, or just about managing the credentials?